# I am using pthreads to speed up my matrix multiplication but not getting correct values

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, matrix-multiplication

I have to calculate the speed of operation for different threads but the matrix size has to be (1000X1 and 1X1000). I have to calculate this using 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 and 512 threads.

my program is returning same values for all the resultant matrix. Where do I make changes?
I am using random number generator to fill the matrices and dynamically allocating and freeing the matrices.

I first kept N = 512 but I was getting segmentation fault core dumped error so I increased the N. How can I use different number of threads to calculate the matrix?
For a 1000X1 and 1X1000 matrix the resulatant matrix is all 18 and gets segmentation fault core dump error.
For 100X1 and 1X100 all values are 3 and the same happens
to compile it you have to use -lpthreads and -fopenmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Each thread computes single element in the resultant matrix
void *mult(void *arg)
{
    int *data = (int *)arg;
    int k = 0, i = 0;

    int x = data[0];
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        k += data[i] * data[i + x];

    int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = k;

    // Used to terminate a thread and the return value is passed as a pointer
    pthread_exit(p);
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, row1, col1, row2, col2, r, sum, no_of_threads;

    printf("Enter the number of rows for matrix 1\n");
    scanf("%d", &row1);
    printf("Enter the number of columns for matrix 1 \n");
    scanf("%d", &col1);
    printf("Enter the number of rows for matrix 2 \n");
    scanf("%d", &row2);
    printf("Enter the number of columns for matrix 2\n");
    scanf("%d", &col2);

    int **a = (int **)malloc(row1 * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(col1 * sizeof(int));

    int **b = (int **)malloc(row2 * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < row2; i++)
        b[i] = (int *)malloc(col2 * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col1; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = (rand() % 9) + 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = (rand() % 9) + 1;
        }
    }

    int N = 1000;

    // declaring array of threads of size row1*col2
    pthread_t *threads;
    threads = (pthread_t *)malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));

    int count = 0;
    int *data = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
            // storing row and column elements in data
            data = (int *)malloc((N) * sizeof(int));
            data[0] = col1;

            for (k = 0; k < col1; k++)
                data[k + 1] = a[i][k];

            for (k = 0; k < row2; k++)
                data[k + col1 + 1] = b[k][j];
        }

    // creating threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
    std:
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,
                       mult, (void *)(data));
    }

    printf("RESULTANT MATRIX IS :- \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        void *k;

        // Joining all threads and collecting return value
        pthread_join(threads[i], &k);

        int *p = (int *)k;
        printf("%d ", *p);
        if ((i + 1) % col2 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++)
    {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++)
    {
        free(b[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:
How do I send multiple arguments through threads as if I read the matrix in my main function, I am not able to pass the values of rows and columns to my mult function. If I read the matrix in mult function then the threads are not working. How do I get it to multiply?

Comment: You are missing key elements of your demonstration. Where's the data? Please fix the issue.

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. Please fix the issue.

Comment: huh? No, you didn't. Someone fixed the indenting for you, but it's still not runnable.

Comment: @ikegami I was fixing it but it told me someone edited it and I can't edit it again. also you have to use -fopenmp and -lpthreads while compiling it

Comment: Yes, that should be mentioned in your question. But as mentioned already, the program expects inputs, and you did not provide them. That should be in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is flawed:

- the destination matrix is not allocated properly
- you pass the same argument to all threads
- the threads do not receive any information regarding where to store the result of the scalar product.

You should allocate an argument structure for each thread and pass the source arrays and destination location.

With the current approach, there are `row1 * col2` scalar products to compute: if you want to use fixed number of threads, you should construct a list of tasks for each thread to process in order to distribute the word among the threads. It is rather easy to do it statically and since all single computations are equivalent in terms of complexity, dynamic distribution does not seem necessary.

Note however that you must wait for all threads to complete before examining and freeing the results. Freeing the arrays as the threads are potentially still accessing the data is among the many causes for undefined behavior in the posted code.

Comment: I updated it, Can you let me know how I to proceed further?

Comment: @ShubhenduDas: do not modify the question this way: it makes the comments and answers inconsistent. Moving the initialization code to the thread function is not correct, you should define a structure for the thread arguments and populate it with the coordinates of the source vectors and destination cell. Make a list of these structures for each thread to process it order. Then start the threads and wait for them to complete.